# RethinkDB repetative query optimisation

Tags: query-optimization, rethinkdb

In RethinkDB's ReQL, if you have to run multiple queries on the same base query, that is the same filtered records, is it better to:

A) filter the base records first and pass their primary keys to the secondary queries, even if it could potentially involve passing thousands of primary keys?

Or

B) include both the base filter and secondary queries in one more complex query?

Background:

This is for a dashboard style application, where the dashboard itself controls the base records, including relationships to other table records (eqJoin) and can be filtered by the user.  Each of the tiles will use data from one or more of those filtered tables, possibly applying additional pre-defined filters, aggregate functions, maps etc. to return the required data to support its UI (tables, forms, charts etc.).

My primary concern is execution time, I know this is a very general question and will depend very much on the data and filters, but as a general rule, if you had to choose one approach or any other approach which would be applied across the board, which would offer the best performance in RethinkDB?